# ASP.NET Website issue - will not load externally

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a site that works fine on the server itself. I can browse to the site from within IIS or by launching a browser on the server itself. However, if I try to access this externally, I get a 404 error.

I have tested DNS for the domain in question ([www.phanetworktest.com](http://www.phanetworktest.com)) and that is not the issue. I was able to create another site with a single, simple HTML page and the site was then accessible outside of the server. I believe it is either a configuration issue with IIS or maybe a problem with the application itself. It is an ASP.NET 4.6 application.

The error when I try to navigate to the site externally is "404 - not found".

There is a variety of other sites also running on this server, including a classic ASP site, an ASP.NET 4.6 website, and two ASP.NET MVC sites.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is your simple HTML page accessible through domain name? If so, then the problem is caused by your asp.net project. and is your project MVC? If so, have you configured routing? You can also create a web form project for testing.

Comment: The simple HTML page is no longer accessible through that domain name. I bound it temporarily to the simple site so I could test DNS and make sure that IIS was properly listening for that web address. The domain is now bound to the ASP.NET site.

Comment: What is access outside the server？How do you access the HTML page?

Comment: What I mean by this is any device outside of the server environment, externally, on the outside of the firewall. So I would enter www.phanetworktest.com into the browser address and after an NS lookup it would resolve to the IP address of the server. From there, IIS would be listening for that domain as I had it bound to the simple single HTML page site. Now, that domain is once again bound to the ASP.NET application. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Clear your cache and cookies, then try it again.

Comment: Yep, tried that and it didn't work. I also tried unplugging the monitor and plugging it back in, but surprisingly that didn't work either:)!

Comment: I suggest you can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis) to view detailed error message in log file.